# Questions about stationery et al

Tags: discussion

At Writers we focus on questions related to writing. However, there are certain other territories that might be covered under writing. For example, people might have questions about what kind of paper to use for business writing or the kinds of envelopes one can use to send a letter in the corporate world (vs. non-corporate world). People may also have questions about what kind of information goes into letterhead or maybe they have questions about posters (covered under technical writing), and so on.

I understand that questions like these are too far away from the central domain of Writers and frankly, I believe that my question even sounds absurd. But what are your views on the same? I doubt we will actually get questions under this domain, but what if?

Comment: Related: [Do we want to answer questions about the mechanical act of writing?](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/291/26)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stationary, like that question about [printers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/1033/what-is-a-good-economical-printer-for-writers)? Closed (and deleted) as off-topic.

Or the [best pen for signing documents](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2876/which-pen-is-best-for-writing-signing-important-documents)? Closed.

Or [how many writers us fountain pens](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/how-many-writers-use-fountain-pens-dip-pens-today)? Clos... WTF? Why is that open?

Ok, the main problem with these questions is, that they are highly subjective. So there is no need to discuss if they are off-topic, they are closed anyway ;)

There may be best practices or even legal regulations (e.g. letterhead), but they also depend on the country, on the industry, stuff like that.

All in all they do not make a good fit. I would say, we deal with them as they come up. Just because I cannot think of an on-topic question in that field, does not mean it doesn't exist.

And now excuse me, I have to cast a close vote ...