# Closing an opinion based question

Tags: discussion

[This](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/2202/how-many-writers-use-fountain-pens-dip-pens-today) question has been around for a while and had even come up in an [answer](https://writers.meta.stackexchange.com/a/797/5909). However, the question is still open.

Is the question not off topic?

Comment: Well, "opinion based" does not mean "off topic" even though it can be both. But why it is still open I have no idea.

Comment: @JohnSmithers True. You were the one who brought this question up and imagine my surprise when I randomly bump into this question and go like 'Why is this thing still open?'

Comment: The question is answerable and about a tool used for writing. I think it's on topic.

Comment: @NeilFein, it's subjective, and it's *not* answerable. Show me how you want to find out how many writers use fountain pens. Why they use them or why not is opinion based. So it may improve your handwriting, I have no clue how it should help for writing techniques.

Comment: I agree with @JohnSmithers in that it is opinion based and one cannot really have a conclusive answer about it. in that respect, I believe, that it should be closed. I am surprised the question has been around for 2 years without "objections"